# position division underneath "absolute" text container

Tags: css

I would like to have an overlay above an image, which as far as I figured position:absolute is the only option. Now the text underneath is getting overlapped by the overlay as soon as the screen-width is below a certain threshold. How can I prevent this?

```css
.text-and-image {
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 5%;
  width: 90%;
  max-height: 80vh;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 10vh;
}

.text-and-image-box{
  width: 100%;
  position:relative;
  height: auto;
  max-height: 75vh;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.text-and-image-image{
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}


.text-and-image-box2{
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: absolute;
  top: 40%;
  left: 55%;
  width: 40%;
  padding: 3%;
  background: white;
}

.text-section{
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  margin-left: 15%;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-and-image">

  <div class="text-and-image-box">
    <img class="text-and-image-image" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1514986888952-8cd320577b68?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MXwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHw%3D&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1055&q=80">
  </div>

  <div class="text-and-image-box2">

    <h3 class="text-and-image-text">Ein schlechtes Messer fährt leichter in die Hand als ins Brot."</h3>
    <p class="text-and-image-text">Jeder Hobby- oder Profikoch braucht gutes Werkzeug. Nur damit macht es Spaß und ist sicher. Solinger Küchenmesser und Stahlwaren bestechen schon seit Jahrhunderten durch ausgezeichnete Qualität, hohe Langlebigkeit und innovative Lösungen. Das merkt man und hat seinen Weg schon in Millionen von Küchen in aller Welt gefunden. Unser Statement: </p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="text-section">
 <h1 id="main-headline"> Bestes deutsches Traditionshandwerk für Ihre Kunden </h1>
 <h2 id="sub-headline">Küchenmesser & Stahlwaren</h2>
 <p class="information">
  Ihre Kunden haben eine hohe Erwartung an Sie
</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use breakpoints (@media rules) to for example add `p {padding-right 40%}` for cases that it looks broken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set a height (35vh worked for me) to `.text-and-image-box2` then you can set the overflow attribute to scroll which prevents the div from resizing:

```
.text-and-image-box2 {
    height: 35vh;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

However, this looks ugly.

CSS media queries can be used. You can set alternative styles based on the device used:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .text-and-image-box2 {
        (alternative styles here)
    }
}
```

Replace the `600px` with the threshold width that the overlap begins at. You could change the font size, etc. so make the div take up less space. You may  need to include more than one of these.

Read more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)

As well as this, I would include the following meta tag:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">`

This sets the viewport so the page looks good on devices which have a small width (such as phones). Any device which has a width of your 'threshold' is likely to be a mobile device so without this the page will look bad anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Use @media for individual screen sizes

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
.text-and-image-box2 {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 2px 2px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
    position: absolute;
    top: 20%;
    left: 35%;
    width: 60%;
    padding: 3%;
    background: white;
}
```

}